# Title, tick, axis labels, nothing is showing in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graph():
  fig = plt.figure()
  data = [[top3_empsearch, top5_empsearch, top7_empsearch], [top3_elastic, top5_elastic, top7_elastic]]
  X = np.arange(3)
  ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
  ax.bar(X + 0.00, data[0], color='b', width=0.25)
  ax.bar(X + 0.25, data[1], color='g', width=0.25)
  ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy (in %)')
  plt.title('Percentage accuracy for selected result in Top-3, Top-5, Top-7 in employee search vs elastic search')
  plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 10))
  colors = {'empsearch':'blue', 'elastic':'green'}
  labels = list(colors.keys())
  handles = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=colors[label]) for label in labels]

  plt.legend(handles, labels)
  plt.style.use('dark_background')
  plt.show()

plot_graph()
```

The outcome of this code is -> [image]

No ticks, no labels, no title nothing is visible and I'm bamboozled. Will appreciate the help.

Comment: You made you axes fill the figure in add_axes. Suggest you let the layout be more automatic and call ax=fig.subplot(1,1,1) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is in this line:

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Looking to the bibliography (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html), you will see that the first parameter of add_axes() function is "rect", which refers to the the dimensions [left, bottom, width, height] of the new axes, all quantitie in fractions of figure width and height. So in your code you are giving exactly the dimensions of the figure, so the title, ticks, labels... are there but hidden. So you have to leave some space, reducing a bit the plot's dimensions. You could do it just by modifying:

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
```

Alternatively, you could replace that line by:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
```

and the result should be the same.

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: The answer works but you know what's strange is that when I ran the same function through jupyter notebook with axes[0,0,1,1] it draws correctly without any missing details and that was my whole point of confusion. Is there difference in the way jupyter vs normal python console render for matplotlib?